# Proving an inequality $\log$ and $e$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This inequality should be fairly easy to show. I think I'm just having trouble looking at it the right way (It's used in a proof without explanation).

$$(1-\frac{1}{\log ^{2} n})^{(2 \log n) -1}\geq e^{-2/\log n}$$

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks
Edit: Log is base 2

Comment: this is wrong, try $n=100$

Comment: you are right @Dr.SonnhardGraubner .  I think it should be $e^{-2/ \log n}$ (the paper has $e^ {1/ \log (n)}$ which is clearly wrong. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $n>2$ are natural numbers and $\log = \log_2$:

$(1 + \frac 1n)^n$ is increasing, $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+ \frac 1n)^n =e $ and $(1+\frac 1x)^x < e$ for $x \ge 1$.

And $(1-\frac 1x)^x > \frac 1e$ for $x \ge 1$.

So $ (1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n})^{\log^2 n} >  e^{-1}$

$( 1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n})^{2\log n} >  e^{\frac{-2}{\log n}}$

$( 1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n})^{2\log n - 1} > \frac {e^{\frac{-2}{\log n}}}{1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n}}$

If $n > 2$ and $\log n = \log_2 n > 1$ then $0< {1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n}} < 1$ and

$( 1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n})^{2\log n - 1} > \frac {e^{\frac{-2}{\log n}}}{1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n}}>e^{\frac{-2}{\log n}} $

If $n = 2$ then

$( 1 - \frac 1{\log^2 n})^{2\log n - 1} =$

$( 1 - \frac 1{\log^2 2})^{2\log 2 - 1} = 0^0$ is undefined.

Likewise if $n=1$ we have division by $0$.

Perhaps $\log = \ln =\log_e$?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The Bound is implicitly asymptotic in the paper, so $n>2$ is fine to assume. I really appreciate the help.